# add items in Adapter

Tags: java, android

I'm new in programming.
I have a problem with filling `GridView` from the Internet. 
Through `AsyncTask`, I parsed much content (img, txt), create and filling database.
And when I call the adapter to `GridView` (`CursorAdapter` or any of the standard adapters), he always fully updates all the already-made content.
Please advise some sort of a way to fill the content `GridView` without changing already completed views, from DB, which actively adds data from the parser.
What adapter and methods, be better to use in this case? I would be very grateful for some guidance or example.
Thank you for taking a few minutes for giving me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if you have a reference to your list adapter, you only need to add an item to your adapter, and then call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the adapter. This will display the new item in your grid view without needing to add all the items again.